# How to integrate PayUMoney iOS SDK in swift project?

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, payumoney

I'm developing an ecommerce iOS app in swift. I want to integrate PayUMoney iOS SDK into my project. Only Objective-C SDK is there. All SO questions, [tutorials](http://objectivecwithsuraj.blogspot.in/2015/07/payumoney-payment-gateway-integration.html) and [documentations](https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Documentations/wiki/8.-iOS-SDK-integration) are in Objective-C only. Is there any way to integrate this SDK into swift project? Please help me.

Comment: I am also stuck with payumoney integration.which tutorial you have followed to complete?

Comment: @Madhumitha did You find that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To integrate *Obj-C* libraries into a Swift Project all  you have to do is use a so-called **Bridging Header**. Those literally work as bridge between the *Obj-C* code and the *Swift* code. Here is an exact representation from the Apple Docs:
[image: Explanation] Basically what this does it let's Swift access everything through the one header file and for Obj-C it generates a .m file with all methods and other code.

1. To add a bridging header, simply create a new `File -> iOS -> Source -> CocoaTouch -> UIViewcontroller` and then as language select *Objective-C*. You can name it `yourNewlyCreatedClass` for example.
   whatever you want as we'll later delete it.
2. Once you do that you will get this Pop Up:
   [image: Pop Up] asking you if you want to create the bridging header. 
   Select the create function and open the newly created file that should be named something like *Briding-Header.h*
3. Now, you can remove the line that say `#import
   "yourNewlyCreatedClass.h"` and replace it with `#import
   <PayUMoney/PayUMoney.h>` or whatever the framework is called.
4. To finish up, you can now delet the two created classes from before. Simply select `yourNewlyCreatedClass.h` and `yourNewlyCreatedClass.m` and you're good to go.

   Congrats, now you can access any of the methods you see in their docs through simply typing them in your swift file.

For further reference, please advise the Apple Docs found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html). Images were used from the official Apple Docs.

Hope that helps,
Julian

Comment: @SatZ did you able to do that

Comment: @VijayvirSingPantlia we did with web integration. Search about **Bridging Header** , it is possible to add it as library.